# How to run a command with a different working directory?

Tags: javascript, deno

In Deno, I know that I can run a command like so:

```js
const process = Deno.run({
  cmd: ["echo", "hello world"]
})
```

How can I run my command with a different working directory?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`cwd`](https://doc.deno.land/builtin/stable#Deno.run) to specify a different path relative to your working directory (or use an absolute path).

```
const process = Deno.run({
  cmd: ["echo", "hello world"],
  cwd: "/path/to/dir"
})
```